# Reading particular char from file in C

Tags: c, file, scanf

I'm new in C programming and I need to write some program which get a character from file. I have text file like this:

```
Grade
Joe Black A
Mark Freeman B
John White C
.
.
.
```

And I have to only read grades (A B C...) from this file and put it to array. It's possible to get only this particular characters not a whole file?

Comment: It's impossible to just *read* the grades from the file, since there's no way to know where they are in the file without looking for the newlines. Of course it's possible to only store the information you care about in your array, but you'll need to show what you've tried; Stack Overflow isn't a "do my homework for me" service (someone will probably do your homework for you and prove me wrong in 3... 2... 1...)

Comment: You can read each line of the file and take the last character.  If you need help on doing this, try writing the code and see what problems you come across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char arr[100];
    int flag=1;
    fp=fopen("try.txt","r");
    while (fgets(arr,100, fp)!=NULL)
    {
        if(flag==1)
        {
            flag=0;
            continue;
        }
        printf("%c\n",arr[strlen(arr)-2]);
    }
}
```

make sure you press enter after last character of last line in the file because we are doing `len-2`(which includes `\n` character).

Comment: Thanks mate, I understand this line "printf("%c\n",arr[strlen(arr)-2]);" but that about this flag? It is skip first line?

Comment: @Patryk: yeah flag is for skipping first line.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You'll probably find it easiest to read the line in (fgets) and then parse the string (trim whitespace from end then read the char after the last whitespace).

Comment: The "last whitespace" in a string read via `fgets()` is typically the `'\n'` and the `char` after that is `''\0``.  Not clear on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the file with `fopen()`.
2. Allocate memory for each line you read with `malloc()`.
3. Read each line in the file using `fgets()`, while you have not yet reached the end of the file (`feof()`).

But how will you know which character is the grade? If you look for characters `'A'` - `'F'` (`strchr()`), you will also find the `'B'` and the `'F'` in Joe Black's and Mark Freeman's last names?

You may find that `strtok()` can help you break a string into smaller pieces on each space, and assuming the data in your file is okay, the last token on every line, if it is only 1 character long, will be the grade.

(Tip for new members: if someone posts an answer you feel is the best, you can "accept" their answer as a way to show appreciation.  Your reputation will thank you.)